# How to add elements to a list on a recursive function that doesn't pass that list as an argument?

Tags: list, recursion, tree, ocaml, binary-tree

The title says much of it, this is the function:

`optimistic: dtree -> int * (int list)`

```
let rec optimistic dt =
  match dt with
  | Decision(choiceL, costL, l, choiceR, costR, r) -> 
    if costL > costR then 0::xs; optimistic r - costR
    else 1::xs ; optimistic l - costL 
  | Chance(eventL, probL, l, eventR, probR, r) ->
    if optimistic l > optimistic r then 0::xs ; optimistic l
    else 1::xs ; optimistic r
  | Outcome -> value, x
;;
```

Essentially, based on the 'route' we take down the binary tree, we will record that path by using 0 (for when we take a left turn) or a 1 (for when we take a right turn) and putting these numbers together to make a list, which we will return in the end.

Problem is, I can't figure out a way for this list to persist through recursion since it is not taken as an argument. Any ideas how to do such thing?

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is that you should have a helper function that *does* take the list as an argument.

If you insist on using imperative techniques, you can have a mutable list value in a more global scope that's modified as you traverse the tree. (Even so, it would be best to have a helper function to avoid putting the modifiable list into the outermost scope.)

Answer (score 0):

You should take the list as an argument but if you don't care about tail-call optimization, you can write this:

```
let rec optimistic dt =
  match dt with
  | Decision(choiceL, costL, l, choiceR, costR, r) -> 
    if costL > costR then
      let c, t = optimistic r in
      c - costR, 0 :: t
    else
      let c, t = optimistic l in
      c - costL, 1 :: t
  | Chance(eventL, probL, l, eventR, probR, r) ->
    let cR, tR = optimistic r in
    let cL, tL = optimistic l in
    if cL > cR then
      cL, 0 :: tL
    else
      cR, 1 :: tR
  | Outcome -> 0, []
;;
```